# download xml from url to inputstream

Tags: java, android, download, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm a beginner in android

I'm a beginner in java

then ... i had no problem developing since I needed an app to download and parse xml from url

then i wrote the following code :

```
    package com.aaa.bbb;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class Login extends Activity {

    String VA_URL = "MYURL";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ("loginbu".equals(v.getId())){
            new DownloadXml1().execute(VA_URL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private class DownloadXml1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
                EditText ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                ProgressBar PB1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                ET1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ET2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                PB1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


            protected InputStream doInBackground(String...f_url) {
                EditText ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String user = ET1.getText().toString();
                String pass = ET2.getText().toString();
                InputStream stream = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    String encoded;
                    encoded = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((user + ":" + pass).getBytes(), 0);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encoded);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                stream = conn.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception ee) {}
            return stream;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inpStream) {
            // Parse Xml
            try {
                inpStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried it without having button and text boxes
I mean deleting the Authorization line + preexecute function + getting edit text value lines ... then running it when the application starts .. but still not working :|

is there any problem with the code ... ???
or if you know another method for downloading and parsing xmls please let me know ...

**update** : LogCat

```
    07-26 14:00:33.647: D/gralloc_goldfish(1092): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-26 14:00:34.559: I/Choreographer(1092): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-26 14:00:35.338: I/Choreographer(1092): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-26 14:00:38.008: I/Choreographer(1092): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-26 14:00:43.498: I/Choreographer(1092): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-26 14:00:43.498: D/AndroidRuntime(1092): Shutting down VM
07-26 14:00:43.608: W/dalvikvm(1092): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.aaa.bbb.Login$DownloadXml1.onPostExecute(Login.java:73)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.aaa.bbb.Login$DownloadXml1.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-26 14:00:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 14:01:07.968: I/Process(1092): Sending signal. PID: 1092 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Do you get any error in your code ? If yes then do post the logcat also.

Comment: You are trying to execute your Asynctask code in `onClick` method but where have you registered your view for clicklistener ?

Comment: i said it dosent work if i put 'new DownloadXML1().execute(VA_URL)' in oncreat ...

Comment: What is the issue if you get any error then please post the logcat.

Comment: here is the logcat :|

Comment: Its showing that your inputstream is getting the null value.

Comment: but i i have tested my url :|

Comment: You might have tested the url but the error which you are getting belongs to the initialization of the views in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute your Asynctask code in onClick method but where have you registered your view for clicklistener ?

If you want to execute the `DownloadXml1()` then you have to write it in your `onCreate()` method. And also initialize all your views in `onCreate()` method not in AsyncTask as below:

> ```
>        EditText ET1;
>          EditText ET2;
>        ProgressBar PB1; 
>   @Override
>  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
>
>      ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
>      ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
>      PB1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
>     if ("loginbu".equals(v.getId())){
>         new DownloadXml1().execute(VA_URL);
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope you will get idea from this. Try out and let me know if any issues.